# PHP use opendir() list directory only and allow to click to display content

Tags: php, view, client-server, client-side

I am new to PHP. I would like to use opendir() to display a clickable list of only directories in a folder(/C:/user), when the user click on one directory on the list, it opens a new tab and shows files inside this directory. How could I do this? I only can found some examples use scandir() to list all folders and files but not separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate PHP which is the server side,
And developing your client side (app, website).
The server side will be able to hunt down the list of folders (on the server itself!), The display theme will be done by the client side.